# Entity Framework Code First Migration For Oracle Database trailing spaces issue

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework, oracle-sqldeveloper

This is the query generated from ef code first approach with oracle db (i got this query from oracle profiler)

```
SELECT "Extent1"."LBRCODE" AS "LBRCODE" FROM "NEO"."D001005" "Extent1" 
WHERE (("Extent1"."CAT" = :p__linq__0) AND ("Extent1"."CATTYPE" = :p__linq__1))
```

this query returns null in c#. i copy this query in SQL Developer Run excecute statement and passed required parameters still returns null data.

When i pass hardcoded(Same) Parameters(which i had passed in execute statement) like this  -

```
SELECT "Extent1"."LBRCODE" AS "LBRCODE" FROM "NEO"."D001005" "Extent1" 
WHERE (("Extent1"."CAT" = 'D') AND ("Extent1"."CATTYPE" = 'SCROLLNO'))
```

above query works perfect and returns data.
what is the issue i am not able to get it. we are migrating our application from SQL Server to oracle(i am new in oracle) with SQL Server everything works fine.

```
Data Types of Parameters -

"CAT"     - CHAR(1) 
"CATTYPE" - CHAR(8)
```

Hint - `CATTYPE` Column contains trailing spaces. 
thanks in advance

Comment: There is no issue. The behaviour is the same in SQL Server. You specified a fixed-length character field. If the values you store arent' exactly 8 characters, the stored value will have spaces. ANSI SQL comparison rules ignore trailing spaces, but that has to be specified as a connection setting. In SQL Server this is controlled by the `ANSI_PADDING` setting. The real fix is to use `VARCHAR(8)` if you intend to store less than 8 characters

Comment: As @PanagiotisKanavos said, `char` type is a fixed-length character which automatically filling whitespaces to remaining unused character space, hence the `WHERE` query must be changed to use `LIKE` clause instead of `=`. If you want to use `=` as equality comparison, try `varchar`/`nvarchar` type instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i cant change db column data type. but hardcoded query working. and generated by ef code first not working why this behavior ?

Comment: I already explained that. It's exactly the same as SQL Server - if you store a small string on a larger fixed-length field, the value will be padded with spaces. *Comparison* ignores the spaces in SQL Server too **ONLY** if you set ANSI_PADDING to ON. It's just ON by default

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto everything works with Sql server. but not with oracle. is there any global way to do this i dont want to change in application. our need to work with both Sql and oracle.

Comment: @deepakneo no, exactly the same works with SQL Server. Just make sure you find and enable the appropriate padding setting in Oracle.

Comment: @deepakneo Probably this may open your mind: [CHAR vs (N)VARCHAR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/b_char.htm) & [RTRIM](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/rtrim.php). AFAIK there is no general option like `SET ANSI PADDING` in Oracle, you may require `RTRIM` function to trim `CHAR` column values. Also check this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12585776/sql-why-pad-spaces-when-comparing-characters.